# Wordpress: Getting images by 'category' taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code and im trying to get the images by category, I have a category name "home-hero" and when I add it into the following code it still displays all the images in the media.

How can i get it to only display all the images under home-hero?

```
<?php
function get_images_from_media_library() {
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'home-hero',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' =>'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
  );
  $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
  return $query_images;
}

function display_images_from_media_library() {
  $imgs = get_images_from_media_library();
  $html = '<div id="media-gallery">';
  global $post;
  if ($imgs->have_posts()) {
    while($imgs->have_posts()) {
      $imgs->the_post();
      $html .= '<img src="' . $post->guid . '" alt="" />';
      $html .=  get_the_date('F j, Y');
    }
  }
  $html .= '</div>';
  return $html;
}
echo display_images_from_media_library();
?>
```

Thanks for taking the time to ready.

Comment: I have a working (incomplete) solution at home, was actually working on the same exact thing last week. Will post later when I get home. I can tell you however, attachments don't have categories, the parent post have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said i a comment, I have a working incomplete solution that I need to finish for a project.

The problem is, attachments don't have categories, just their parents have, so it is impossible with a simple query to get attachments from a specific category

You will need to run two queries here, the first query will get all the parent posts from a given category, the second query will use the parent post ID's to get the attachments from all the parent posts given

In both queries, you just need to get the post ID field, this will dramatically speed up your query, and you will use the returned attachment ID's (`$attachments->posts`) with [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

### Just a few notes on the code

- This code was meant to go into a function and `$post_type`, `$taxonomy` and `$term` is supposed to be retrieved dynamically. You can hardcode values to these three variables or also make it dynamic in your function
- You don't need to use a `tax_query`, you can simply use the category parameters if you use the build-in taxonomy `category`. I just used a `tax_query` so that the function-to-be can be used for any taxonomy. If you leave the `tax_query` for build-in categories, remember, the taxonomy is `category` and the term will be the category ID (I've set field to `term_id`)
- This code requires at least PHP 5.4. If you have a version older than 5.4, simply change the array wrapper `[]` to `array()`

Here is the code:

```
$args1 = [
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy'          => $taxonomy,
            'field'             => 'term_id',
            'terms'             => $term,
            'include_children'  => false
        ],
    ],  
];
$post_parents = new WP_Query($args1); 

if( $post_parents->posts ) {    

    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'posts__in'      => $post_parents->posts,
    ];
    $attachments = new WP_Query($args); 

}
?><pre><?php var_dump($attachments->posts); ?></pre><?php
```

Hope this helps you in your project

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this :

```
<?php
$images = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'category__in' => array(cat_ids))  );
if ( !empty($images) ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID).'<br />';
        echo $image->post_title .'<br />';
        the_attachment_link( $image->ID, true );
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: attachments don't have categories, only the post parents have, this won't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Pieter, yes I agree by default attachments does not have categories, but we can also add support for attachments to have categories like this => 

function register_taxonomy_for_images() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_for_images' );